# Sun Netra 240 not booting to ALOM

Tags: installation, boot, sun

I inherited a Sun Netra 240 with no OS installed (indeed, with no hard drives). I did some googling, and came up with a few manuals, all of which I downloaded:

Netra 240 PROM Guide

Netra 240 ALOM Guide

Netra 240 Installation Guide

Netra 240 Service Manual

Solaris OS Installation Guide

After reading through them, I came up with the correct hard drives, which I have installed. I also found that I needed a DB9 to RJ45 patch cable and an appropriate machine with a DB9 port. I have the requisite physical machine that will allow me to interface with ALOM on the 240 (It's a PowerEdge 2600 running Debian 7, if it matters). I am using Minicom as a serial interface.

So my understanding at this point is that I should plug the DB9 end into the Poweredge, the RJ45 end into the Netra, turn on the Netra (assuming the Poweredge is on, I'm logged in, have Minicom running at 9600/8/N/1 on ttyS0) and I should see some sort of boot sequence.

*However*, I get nothing via Minicom. I also don't get any diagnostic lights on the Netra, except a green light at the NETMGMT port on the back of the box, as well as a green light at the PSU. For the record, I have also tried ttyS1, tty0, and tty1 as well.

Does anyone have any profound wisdom for me? Failing that, could someone please point out whatever ridiculously simple step I missed?

Of course, feel free to ask for any pertinent information I may have omitted. I've included everything I know to include, but that doesn't appear to mean much at this point.

Additional information edit: The Netra has a pair of UltraSPARC IIIi CPUs, with 24 GB of matched DDR3 PC2700 ECC RAM. The RAM is 6 4GB sticks, 4 sticks on CPU0, 2 sticks on CPU1 Bank 0. The RAM is known to work (tested in the PowerEdge), but the CPUs are not known. I don't have a way to test the CPUs until the Netra powers on.

Comment: It's been too long, but would you need a null modern adapter? Or does the rj-45/serial cable handle that? I have used serial to Bluetooth adapters as well.

Comment: My understanding from the manuals is that the RJ45/DB9 cable handles that. As far as I can see, it's strictly plug and play, no additional hardware required beyond the cable I'm using.